# NoSuchElementException identifying username field within Instagram login page using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, instagram, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

I am getting this error and can't solve it.
[image: Image of the error]

This is all the code. I heard adding waiting time might solve the issue but not sure how to add it.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com");

IWebElement userName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
```

Comment: Please post the actual error text and not a linked screenshot.  It will help people find your issue more effectively down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the Until method from an instance of a WebDriverWait class, which you could tell to wait until it finds, say, element username. For example:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Name("username")));
```

Hope that helps, and if you're crawling Instagram is for the right purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

The identify the **username** field on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) login page you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *ExpectedConditions*:

  ```
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com");
  IWebElement userName = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("username")));
  ```
- Using *lambda* expression:

  ```
  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com");
  IWebElement userName = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(x=> x.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not necessarily your code 100%. It really depends on how you are hitting the site. The way I access IG is to login from another site. When I lick login to IG I get the IG popup. Then I need to:

-switch to the popup

-Login

-Handle all of the other questions

-then switch to main

You may need to tweak this based on what you are doing but this should work.

```
    public void InstagramLogin()
    {
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='uppy-DashboardTab-btn']//div[contains(text(), 'Instagram')]")).Click();
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Connect to Instagram')]")).Click();
        Driver.SwitchToPopup();
        Driver.WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath("//input[@name='username']"));
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='username']")).SendKeys("MyEmail@gmail.com");
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='password']")).SendKeys("myPassword");
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']")).Click();
        Driver.WaitForElementDisplayed(By.XPath("//button[text()='Not Now']"));
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='Not Now']").Click();
        bool ele = Driver.IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Continue')]"));
        if (ele)
        {
            Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Continue')]")).Click();
            Driver.WaitForElementNoLongerDisplayed_byXPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Continue')]");
        }
        Driver.GoToMainHandle();
    }
```